# Complete isolation of two hard drives in a laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, multi-boot

I have a Lenovo T450s laptop which comes with an SSD (*Drive A*) with Windows 7 Professional installed. On top of that I installed a second SSD (*Drive B*) (M2) with Windows 10. I can choose the drive to boot from when the laptop starts so everything works fine.

Since both drives are "boot" drives, I have made sure that one cannot see the other, because if I access one drive from the other, then the "boot" section gets destroyed and I can no longer boot from the second one.

To give an example, if boot from Drive A and access the Drive B from "My Computer", then the next time I try to boot from Drive B, it needs a repair which is not always successful. The same goes for the other way round.

To avoid that issue I have "uninstalled" the hard drives from Device Manager for each OS respectively.

However, the issue I have is that when my Win 10 does a major update, it re-scans (apparently) everything, and tries to access the Drive A again messing up with the boot sector and basically destroying the drive. For the moment, the only solution I have is to always put Win 10 on a "metered connection", so it does not do any updates. Every now and then, I unscrew Drive A and allow Win 10 to update. Obviously, this is not a sustainable solution.

So to conclude, my question is: **Is there any way to make sure the two drives are completely isolated from each other and no update, or system scan, will be able to see them?**

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**TL/DR:** *Laptop with two different hard drives and two different OS's, one messing up the other. How do you stop that?*

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards,
George

Comment: You would have to unmount the volume. You can do that with a script that runs when a user logs into their profile.

Comment: If both contain Windows it should be supported and easly possible for the Windows 10 boot manager to also report Windows 7 and boot it. As for complete isolation: Not as long as they are part of the same system. But as Ramhound said you could use script etc. to make them almost  "isolated".

Comment: Thank you both. I appreciate the help.

Just a clarification. Assuming that a system update is running, wouldn't it still be possible that the disk is "visible" to the OS (after a restart for example) before the script actually runs and unmounts the second volume?